# show TextView and Button on the ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

**Want to show the TextView and Button on the ImageView I try but ImageView hides the Button and TextView Help me what I can do I try it in different Layouts I update the new code but same issue face**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageview"
    >

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_booking"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_booking"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your full xml code here . some part is still missing.

Comment: Sagar Nayak I edit or update the code now

Comment: you want to show button and textview over the imageview ? do you have any image for the imageview set ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as your root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </ImageView>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/text_booking"
        />
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your Main LinearLayout (First one) to RelativeLayout

2) In your Sub LinearLayout (Second one) use -

```
android:layout_above="@+id/imageview"
android:alignParentBottom="true"
```

**UPDATE**

Please Check it -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/imageview"
android:alignParentBottom="true"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_booking"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
    android:weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Onkar Nane I donot understand please explain in code?

Answer (score 0):

look at my code i recently use it i use the parent layout(RelativeLayout) and set the bacground image for parent layout also i change background in java and inside parent layout add images and text what you want.......!
 hope it will help you.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/frontLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/note0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/onecircle"
                android:tag="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageOne"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageOne"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageOne"
                android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/twocircle"
                android:tag="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageThree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageTwo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageSix"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageSix"
                android:background="@drawable/threecircle"
                android:tag="3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageFour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageTwo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageTwo"
                android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fourcircle"
                android:tag="4"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageFive"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageTwo"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageEight"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageEight"
                android:background="@drawable/fivecircle"
                android:tag="5"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines and my issue is resolved.

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_booking"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_booking"
```

Answer (score 0):

strange everyone suggested to you to use `RelativeLayout` while you should use `FrameLayout` for this kind of stuff. its pretty easy to achieve that with FrameLayout rather than `RelativeLayout` as the `RelativeLayout` is pretty expensive when it comes to drawing. to achieve what you asking for you should use this simple combination:

```
FrameLayout>ImageView>LinearLayout(with layout_gravity){Button,TextView}/>
```